# Multiprocessing callback message

Tags: python, callback, multiprocessing

I have long running process, that I want to keep track about in which state it currently is in. There is N processes running in same time therefore multiprocessing issue.

I pass [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) into process to report messages about state, and this `Queue` is then read(if not empty) in thread every couple of second.

I'm using Spider on windows as environment and later described behavior is in its console. I did not try it in different env.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Lock 
import time

def test(process_msg: Queue):        
    try:
        process_msg.put('Inside process message')

        # process...

        return # to have exitstate = 0
    except Exception as e:
        process_msg.put(e)

callback_msg = Queue()
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    p = Process(target = test,
                args = (callback_msg,))
    p.start()                  

time.sleep(5)
print(p)

while not callback_msg.empty():
    msg = callback_msg.get()
    if type(msg) != Exception:
        tqdm.write(str(msg))
    else:
        raise msg
```

Problem is that whatever I do with code, it never reads what is inside the `Queue`(also because it never puts anything in it). Only when I switch to dummy version, which runs similary to threading on only 1 CPU `from multiprocessing.dummy import Process,Queue,Lock`

Comment: consider posting the solution you've found as an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `test` function have to be in separate file.